# Anonymous function appears to override another?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

With this code:

```
function printStuff(thing1, thing2) {
  console.log(thing1 + ', ' + thing2); 
};

function callWith() {
  theFunc = arguments[0];
  theArgs = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
  return function() {
    theFunc.apply(this, theArgs);
  };
};

x = callWith(printStuff, "apples", "cheese");
y = callWith(printStuff, "monkeys", "bananas");
x();
y();
```

...why is it that x and y seem to hold the same function? How do I get the desired behavior (i.e., store two different functions which always run printStuff with the parameters they were given when created)?

Comment: You declare a function `callWith` but call `callWith2`. Where's `callWith2`?

Comment: Also, the problem is because you are declaring `theFunc` and `theArgs` without `var`. They become global variables, and are therefore shared

Comment: sorry, forget to fix that. was simplifying a more complex example to show the important part.

Comment: Ah! I see. I am not very familiar with Javascript. How odd, making the lack of an annotation default to a global variable...

Comment: Would anyone like to explain why I have been downvoted, since whoever did so didn't feel like providing any helpful feedback?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a different NEW instant of the printStuff method like this --

```
function printStuff(thing1, thing2) {
  console.log(thing1 + ', ' + thing2); 
};

function callWith() {
  theFunc = arguments[0];
  theArgs = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
  return new function() { // RETURN A NEW INSTANCE SO THAT IT HAS ITS OWN ARGUMENTS
    theFunc.apply(this, theArgs);
  };
};

x = callWith(printStuff, "apples", "cheese");
y = callWith(printStuff, "monkeys", "bananas");
x();
y();
```

Comment: While I am certainly no javascript expert, it would appear that you are not correct, since the advice provided in Ian's comment works without your addition of a `new` statement.

Comment: Your answer works but also gives me an error in the console (in Chrome 36). Ian's suggestion works without throwing an any errors. Also, the issue about global variables is pretty fundamental problem in the way I originally was doing things.